# Iconbitmap :: file not found in tkinter python3

Tags: python, tkinter, bitmap, icons

I tried as the following , but the icon failed to render, is the path not recognize?

My code as follows : -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import pygame as game
import webbrowser
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
# TK's :

#root.geometry("1500x800")
#root.wm__iconbitmap("") # ONLY WORK WELL WITH .ico

        #root.tk.TK.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file='logo.ico'))
   # def fullscreen():
   #     fullscreen.fullscreen()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    #root.resizable(False, False) 
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    root.geometry("1500x800")
    root.wm_iconbitmap("logo.ico")
    app = cerebro()
    #cerebro.master.iconbitmap('cerebrales 48x48.ico')
    root.mainloop()
```

The error I had received:

```
Exception has occurred: TclError
bitmap "logo.ico" not defined
  File "C:\Users\John Melody\Documents\MEGAsync\Cebebrales-Braintech\main.py", line 110, in main
    root.wm_iconbitmap("logo.ico")
  File "C:\Users\John Melody\Documents\MEGAsync\Cebebrales-Braintech\main.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()
```

It is something I did miss? Or probably I code it wrong? I have intended the icon to run in every window

Comment: It simply means the file `logo.ico` is not found. Did you double check the file location?

Comment: Yes I do sir, Is in the current folder --- same with the .py file .

Comment: Try to specify the full path of your `icon`. Also I noticed that you are using the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` but the error shows its on windows. Are you on windows or Mac?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, Before this Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried be specific, to the path. But it still shows , no such file.

Comment: upper/lower case problem? make sure to double check the case of the file extension as well.

Comment: Nope. The case is match.

Comment: Can you valid the full path of the icon by `glob`? It seems kind of weird even providing full path doesn't show the icon.

Comment: So what was wrong? I am curious.

Comment: My glob had a problem. So I reinstall the entire thing. It worked now